# Turn a file and data into an outputStream and convert from an inputStream to a file and data

Tags: android, wear-os

I need to transmit a file and data to a wearable device and am using the [ChannelClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelClient). I am sending a variety of data (a file and a variety of variables) so the getInputStream and getOutputStream seem to be the right approach (as opposed to sending a file).

How do I package up a collection of variables with a file and send them in an outputStream and how do I unpack them from the inputStream?

I am getting this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: d.b.a.m.a` when using the following code:

**Phone**

```
String node = settingsRepository.getNode();
String path = "/channel/mobile";

ChannelClient channelClient = Wearable.getChannelClient(getContext());
channelClient.openChannel(node,path).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ChannelClient.Channel>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(ChannelClient.Channel channel) {
           Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");

           channelClient.getOutputStream(channel).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<OutputStream>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(OutputStream outputStream) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "channelClient.getOutputStream.onSuccess: ");
                     

                      File file = new File("/data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/files/icon-8.png");
                      TestObject testObject = new TestObject("test",file);
                      Log.d(TAG, "channelClient.getOutputStream.onSuccess: name=" + testObject.getName());

                      ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
                      out.writeObject(testObject);
                      out.flush();
                      out.close();
                }
          })
      }
 })
```

And how do I unpack them on the Wearable?

**Wearable**

```
 Task<InputStream> inputStreamTask = Wearable.getChannelClient(getApplicationContext()).getInputStream(channel);
 inputStreamTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InputStream>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(InputStream inputStream) {
           Log.d(TAG, "addOnSuccessListener.onSuccess: ");
            
           try {

                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
               
                TestObject testObject = (TestObject) in.readObject();
                Log.d(TAG, "addOnSuccessListener.onSuccess: name=" + testObject.getName());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "addOnSuccessListener.onSuccess: error=" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
 });
```

**TestObject Class**

```
 public class TestObject implements Serializable {

     String name;
     File file;

     public TestObject(String name, File file) {
         this.name = name;
         this.file = file;
     }

      public String getName() {
         return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }

      public File getFile() {
          return file;
      }

      public void setFile(File file) {
         this.file = file;
      }
 }
```

Comment: What you write to the output stream is what you read from the inputstream. So just try some strings and lines to begin with.

Comment: I changed the sentence. Hope it helps. I have used other methods to either send strings or files, but I need to send both in the same channel/connection. How do I bundle them together and unpack them  on the other side?

Comment: `the getInputStream and getOutputStream seem to be the right approach` If you mean: Sender writes the data an outputstream and receiver reads that data from an inputstream then yes that is a normal approch.

Comment: `How do I bundle them together and unpack them on the other side?` That is completely up to you. As you know what you write you also know how to read and have to interprete the readed data.

Comment: Have you ever packaged a file with variables using inputStream/outputStream? If so how did you do it? Do you have an example? Is there a specific object I should extend to do this?

Comment: If you have a variable `int number=23;` And then `String line = "number: " + number;`. Then you could write that line to the outputstream using `....writeLine(line);`. The receiving side uses `String line = ....readLine();`. It's the same as with communication over sockets or posting data to a webserver. Now read my first comment again.

Comment: What would you do if you had a string, an int, then a file coming through the stream?

Comment: Please show the code where you send a string and an int and receive them ok. Dont use ObjectStreams. When you manage that i will tell you how to send and receive a file. But nothing will be new as it is always done the same as with socket communication. It is strange that you dont tell if your file transfder works with those object streams.

Comment: Will do. Thanks. I used Wearable.getChannelClient(getApplicationContext()).receiveFile(channel, fileUri, false) and it worked, but I needed more than the file.

Comment: outputStream does not have writeLine(), it has write(byte[]), write(int), write(byte[], int, int)

Comment: Yes, i know  you can use that too to write lines.

Comment: @blackapps, why did you say "Dont use ObjectStreams"? I'm onto a new problem, but same pattern. I need a byte[], but that means I need to break down every object to a byte[] property by property and am trying to convert a Date property.

Comment: I give up. I see nothing of the suggestions i did in new code.

Comment: I didn't end up sending the file, I'm sending a byte[] composed of each of the objects properties w/an index including the variable sized image. I never actually am writing to a file at this point. Sorry for not adding everything. I just had to try a few different ways to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DataOutputStream and DataInputStream.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html

It encodes types like a string with a prefix https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF()

> Reads in a string that has been encoded using a modified UTF-8 format. The general contract of readUTF is that it reads a representation of a Unicode character string encoded in modified UTF-8 format; this string of characters is then returned as a String.
> First, two bytes are read and used to construct an unsigned 16-bit integer in exactly the manner of the readUnsignedShort method . This integer value is called the UTF length and specifies the number of additional bytes to be read

readFully will read into a byte array.

Comment: I updated the post. I am trying to use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream hoping this might accomplish the same approach you recommend, just with Object vs Data.